# Using codeigniter to set a value in database and it will return the output to same page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image]

I marked the like button with red color. Whenever user clicks on the like button like quantity will be increased and it will return the same page with increased values.like initially my post like is 0.whenever user click on the like button it will be 1.following code is controller code

```
public function like_count(){
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
    $like=$this->tourism_model->post_likes($post_id);
    if ($like) {
    $data['full_post_results']=$this->tourism_model->get_full_post($post_id);
    $data['all_comments']=$this->tourism_model->get_comments($post_id);
    $data['full_post_details']='full_post_details';
    $data['full_post_title']='Forum :: Post Description';
    $this->load->view('Forum/forum_home',$data);
    }
}
```

following code is model code.

```
public function post_likes($post_id) { 
    $this->db->where('post_id', $post_id);
    $this->db->set('like','like+1',FALSE);
    $result = $this->db->update('forum_posts');

 }
```

It should work, but it doesn't work, instead it shows an error:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'like = like+1 WHERE `post_id` = '14' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is here

```
 $this->db->set('like','like+1',FALSE);
```

Because the `like` in `like+1` is not a php variable and (I am guessing) that the like field type is a number and you are sending it a string value.

You will need to pass the current total number of likes to the model (or retrieve it in the model). This shows if you pass in the current total.

```
public function post_likes($post_id, $total_likes) { 
  $this->db->where('post_id', $post_id);
  $this->db->set('like', ++$total_likes, FALSE);
  $result = $this->db->update('forum_posts');
}
```

Comment: like is a attribute of my forum_posts table.i want to do like,whenever a user clicks on the like button it will go database and increase the number that i have done like+1.that means whatever the like number you just add with 1 and now return back the total likes to the same page  where user clicked like button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE forum_posts set like = like + 1 where post_id = $post_id");
```

Executing this query should give expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Like is a mysql own keyword.this is why it shows error now i just changed it into post_like.now it works.